# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons

I received down-votes for this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/753966/looking-for-a-forum-with-anonymity-support

Now my understanding is that it is not a question which has readily available answers on the internet (trust me, I have been trying for four days now). And it involves a forum/communication channel where users can chat anonymously. In my opinion - and I asked myself this - before posting it here.

It has been 'put on hold for closing' as of now. I have edited it but I have received only downvotes but no explanation. Can you tell me how should I modify the question so that it meets the community standards? Or if it is not suitable at all for the site at its core, I would like to know the reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Basically the community consensus is that software recommendation questions are off topic for superuser. You *can* ask them on Software recommendations, as long as you meet the quality criteria.

There's another issue here - SE as a whole isn't really a replacement for good research - While you have a clearly articulated idea of what you think you need - the fact that you've not actually looked very deeply at alternatives may not be in your favour. You're talking big picture - but not the implementation details - and a good software request basically is about trying alternatives, working out what dosen't work for you, and trying to get something as near as possible. Its not about spoonfeeding an answer (or as they call it in programmer circles - GIMMETHECODEZ).

As is, you could be using anything from IRC with a public log, to a forum with very lax settings for user registration, to a 4chan style message board

Comment: Ok! I get the idea. Thanks! :)